# Checkbox is not working in rails-backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, checkbox

I have rails model article receive_letters:boolean. And I have backbone in my application. In backbone view I have smth like it:

```
<form id="new-article" name="article">
<div class="field">
 <label for="receive_letters">Подписаться на новостную рассылку </label>
 <input type="text" name="receive_letters" id="receive_letters" value="<%= receive_letters %>">
</div>
```

It's working fine. But then I change type from "text" to "checkbox", it have value = null.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

Template (new.jst.ejs):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="receive_letters" id="receive_letters">
```

View (new_view.js.coffee):

```
events: {
  "click input:checkbox": "check"
  }
check: (e) ->  
  if e.currentTarget.checked == true
    e.currentTarget.value = "true"
  else
    e.currentTarget.value = "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

For checkbox, you also need to changed from the `value` attribute to the `checked` attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="receive_letters" id="receive_letters" checked="<%= receive_letters %>">
```

Comment: but now, by default it's checked but I got value = null, then I 'm clicking on checkbox, every time I got value = true. wtf?

Comment: In dev. tools in chrome it seems like it's always checked, and when I'm clicking on it, every time value sets to "on"